# Get a particular message from ZMQ Sub Queue

Tags: python, filter, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a python messaging application that uses ZMQ. Each object has a PUB and a SUB queue, and they connect to each other. In some particular cases I want to wait for a particular message in the SUB queue, leaving the ones that I am not interested for later processing.

Right now, I am getting all messages and queuing those I am not interested in a Python Queue, until I found the one I am waiting for. But his means that in each processing routing I need to check first in the Python Queue for old messages. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

A zmq publisher doesn't do any queueing... it drops messages when there isn't a SUB available to receive those messages.

The better way in your situation would be to create a generic sub who only will subscribe to certain messages of interest. That way you can spin up all of the different SUBs (even within one thread and using a zmq poller) and they will all process messages as they come from the PUB....

This is what the PUB/SUB pattern is primarily used for. Subs only subscribe to messages of interest, thus eliminating the need to cycle through a queue of messages at every loop looking for messages of interest.

Comment: I already have an IOLoop running and I can easily add another callback. But the problem that I see is that in many cases, I only need one message. So I would have to create a socket, subscribe to a topic and then drop the socket.

Comment: If you only need one socket, I'd look at not using the Sub pattern... Use a req/rep sockets to tell the 'publisher' which message you're interested in and have it respond with the requested message. You're trying to use the Pub-Sub pattern in a situation suited for another pattern

Comment: Yes, but I have to ask to the publisher frequently: Do you have my message?. Another thing that I thought is using PUB/SUB to notify the subcriber that a message is ready, and then the subscriber use REP/REQ to get it.

Comment: Your last work series would probably work. The issue is that if you have more than one SUB connected to the publisher who is looking for the same message, you could reach a race condition on which sub gets the req/rep first. If you only have one sub per message subscription, then this wouldn't be an issue...